# RTMP Flowplayer Issue

Tags: javascript, rtmp, flowplayer

I'm trying to access a RTMP stream with Flowplayer. I've been given a rtmp location (rtmp://xyz.com/flash/fs-93e3010000000000). Which I have set netConnectionUrl to. But I'm not sure what to set 'url' to?

My code is pretty much the same as http://blog.mydeo.com/2010/03/04/embedding-live-streams-with-flowplayer/

Edit:

I'll find out what service they are using, they just gave us a RTMP url.

What mine looks like at the moment:

```
$f("fms", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {

clip: {
    url: 'livestream',
    // configure clip to use influxis as our provider, it uses our rtmp plugin
    provider: 'rtmp',
    live : true
},

// streaming plugins are configured under the plugins node
plugins: {

    // here is our rtpm plugin configuration
    rtmp: {
        url: 'flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
        // netConnectionUrl defines where the streams are found
        netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://mystream.com/flash/fs-93e3010000000000',
    }
}
});
```

The stream itself works with MPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

The *netConnectionUrl* is the url to the server (*rtmp://mystream.com*) along with the application name (*flash*, in this case). The *url* should be set to the stream name (*fs-93e3010000000000*).

So:

```
plugins.rtmp.netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://mystream.com/flash'
clip.url: 'fs-93e3010000000000'
```

You can read more [here](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error ? you rtmp server is working ? Which service are you using ?

This is what i used for live video streaming (same as what you are using) :

```
flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
    clip: {  
        url: 'livestream',
        provider: 'rtmp',
        live: true
    },
    plugins: {
        // RTMP streaming plugin
        rtmp: {
            url: 'flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://my_ip/live'
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using red5 video server but this is the same for FMS.

Edit: You can test your rtmp with mplayer.

mplayer rtmp://your_ip/live

Comment: Hi, I updated with the code of what I have. At the moment there are no errors, the loading spinner just keeps spinning. I'm not sure on the service I'll find out.

Comment: I can confirm the stream works with mplayer. I think the issue is with the 'url'. I'm not sure what to provide here or how to find out what to provide.

Comment: Since i don't know what your are using and more information i can't help you more. Feel free to contact your video streaming service for this information. Good luck

Comment: Hi, I put the rtmp stream in to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2918563/flvplayback.swf and it returned the file name mp4:flvz_945.flv. Trying to play it in that player doesn't work but that might be the player itself. I have tried that as the URL, without the .flv without any luck...